# Requisição AJAX Wordpress com problemas

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

Estou desenvolvendo um template de formulário dentro de um tema wordpress. Preciso que os dados do formulário sejam enviados via e-mail para um determinado endereço via AJAX. Aqui está o tratamento do formulário em JS:

```
var FormData = function(){
var user_name;
var user_email;
var user_message;

this.setName = function(name){
    this.user_name = name;
}

this.getName = function(){
    return this.user_name;
}

this.setEmail = function(email){
    this.user_email = email;
}

this.getEmail = function(){
    return this.user_email;
}

this.setMessage = function(message){
    this.user_message = message;
}

this.getMessage = function(){
    return this.user_message;
}

this.nameIsValid = function(){
    if(this.user_name != ''){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

this.emailIsValid = function(){
    if(this.user_email != ''){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

this.messageIsValid = function(){
    if(this.user_message != ''){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

this.formIsValid = function(){
    if((this.nameIsValid() && this.emailIsValid() && this.messageIsValid())){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    user_object = new FormData();
});
```

Alguns podem achar desnecessário tudo isso pra validar um formulário. Mas fiz apenas pra fins de estudo mesmo. Omitindo os métodos que julgo não fazerem diferença, prossigo.

```
$('#form-contact').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

user_object.setName($('input[name=user_name]').val());
user_object.setEmail($('input[name=user_email]').val());
user_object.setMessage($('#user_message_textarea').val());

if(user_object.formIsValid()){
    var formData = JSON.stringify(user_object);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: formData,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            $('#form-contact').trigger('reset');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Deu erro aqui!");
        }
    });
} else {
    alert("Este formulário não é válido!");
}
```

Quero mandar o objeto em notação AJAX pro método do PHP. Agora o código server-side:

```
function sendMail(){
    $obj = json_decode($_POST['formData']);

    $user_name    = $obj->{'user_name'};
    $user_email   = $obj->{'user_email'};
    $user_message = $obj->{'user_message'};

    $send = mail('pedrovinicius777@gmail.com', 'Contato pelo Site',      $user_message);
    if ($send) {
        return json_encode("Certinho!");
    } else {
        return json_encode("Deu erro!");
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_sendMail', 'sendMail');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sendMail', 'sendMail');
```

Agora o problema! Quando eu envio o form, faço o debug da requisição AJAX, e está dando status 200. Inclusive, recebo a mensagem de sucesso como resposta. No entanto, a função PHP não é realmente executada e não recebo e-mail algum.

Onde eu errei?

Comment: Onde é que você chama a função `sendMail()` no PHP?

Comment: Na verdade não chamo a função no PHP. O sendMail é uma função do PHP que apenas decodifica o objeto json e usa como argumento pra função mail. No caso, esse objeto json é passado no momento da requisição.

Comment: @Sergio, em teoria, o `sendMail` deveria ser definido *dentro* do objeto `formData`, mas isso não está no código exibido... . . . .Pedro, qual *"**função** não é realmente executada"*? O `mail()` do PHP? Não está claro qual é o erro que você está falando, pois mostrou um monte de código pra no final falar de outra coisa (?).

Comment: Sim @brasofilo. A função mail() que não executa. A função em success no javascript é executada. Os dados estão sendo enviados pra função do php como objeto json, mas por algum motivo, a função no php não está sendo executada ou algo está errado.

Comment: Tente com `wp_mail` e [ativando o SMTP](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75957/12615)

Comment: @brasofilo, eu já tentei essa também :-/
SMTP ativado. Meu código está correto?

Comment: Como já disse, você fala de Ajax, formulário, JS, WordPress, mas no fim seu problema é PHP Mail :/ Se quer resolver esse problema, por favor, edite a pergunta para refletir isso (citando que já tentou wp_mail e smtp). . . . Eu faria alguns ajustes de segurança e uso de funções nativas do WP, mas se o código funciona e a requisição Ajax retorna corretamente, então sim, o código está ok. Seu problema está em outro lugar...

Comment: @brasofilo, todos são assuntos relacionados. Apenas descrevi o problema com seus detalhes, pois não sei onde está o meu erro e pensei que assim seria mais fácil de entender. Mas tudo bem.

Comment: É que acho que não tem a ver uma coisa com outra, e você está concentrando detalhes técnicos onde não há nada errado... Confere os resultados no SO para `[php] debug mail`.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer essa chamada de outra forma que vou explicar abaixo:

Utilize a função wp_enqueue_script pra registrar seu script (informações completas no Codex do Wordpress http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

Breve explicação:

$handle = Nome para o script, por exemplo bootstrap-script;

$src = Caminho para o seu arquivo;

$deps = Se existem outro arquivos que precisam ser carregados antes;

$ver = Versão para o script;

$in_footer = Se deverá se exibido no footer ou não;

Após você fazer essa chamada você adiciona a linha abaixo (informações completas no Codex do Wordpress http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

```
wp_localize_script( $handle, $name, $data );
```

Explicação:

$handle = O nome do script que você registrou anteriormente;

$name = Nome que ficará disponível no seu tema para requisições Ajax;

$data = Endereço do arquivo responsável pelas requisições. Como no Wordpress o arquivo 
responsável pelas requisições ajax é o admin-ajax.php, você pode colocar dessa forma admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );

Com essa configuração agora no seu tema irá existir uma variável que pode ser usada no url da chamada Ajax.

Para que funcione, você precisa criar sua função e passar como parâmetro do gancho add_action da seguinte forma:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nome_acao', 'nome_funcao_php' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_nome_acao', 'nome_funcao_php' );
```

Explicando:

A chamada ao wp_ajax é para registrar sua função para usuário logados e o wp_ajax_nopriv é para usuário não logados no gerenciador, dessa forma podendo ser usada no site inteiro.

Agora na sua função javascript faça:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    url: NOME_VARiAVEL_AJAX,
    data: 'action=nome_acao_ajax&' + formData,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        $('#form-contact').trigger('reset');
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("Deu erro aqui!");
    }
});
```

Onde o NOME_VARiAVEL_AJAX é o mesmo que você criou no wp_localize_script();

Você precisa passar um parâmetro action com o nome da função que você quer chamar no seu php, nesse caso é o nome da ação que você deu no add_action.

Passando o nome da ação o Wordpress faz o resto quando houver uma requisição Ajax.